# Suppose for all value of $r$ expression for Effective Potential Energy $U_{eff}$ is zero, does that mean $F(r)$ is zero?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, differentiation

Suppose for all value of $\textbf{r}$ expression for Effective Potential Energy ($U_{eff}$) is zero, does that mean $F(\textbf{r})$ is zero?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer is no.

Note
$U_{eff}(r)=\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}+U(r)=0$

Take derivative of both sides yield:

$\frac{-L^2}{\mu r^3}+\nabla U(r)=0$

This gives

$F(\vec{r})=-\nabla U(r)=\frac{-L^2}{\mu r^3}$

Thus, in general only if angular momentum is zero, force of all value $\vec{r}$  is zero.